# Show a Representation is Indecomposable

Tags: representation-theory

I am working through the open course notes from MIT for Representation Theory.

One problem given is
Let $A = k[x_1,...,x_n]$ and $I \subset A$ be any ideal in $A$ containing all homogenous polynomials of degree $\geq N$.  Show that $A/I$ is an indecomposable representation of $A$.

My thinking so far is 
If $\pi$ is the quotient map $A \to A/I$, and  $b \in A, a \in A/I$ then it has the action
$ a \mapsto a\pi(b)$ I believe, but I am not sure where to proceed from here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $M = M_1 \oplus M_2$.  If $1$ is in either of these, say $M_1$, then automatically $M = M_1$ and $M_2 = 0$.

It might happen that $1$ splits, i.e. $1 + f \in M_1$ and $f \in M_2$ with the degree of $f$ greater than zero.  Let $\alpha$ be the number such that $f^\alpha \ne 0$ but $f^{\alpha + 1} = 0$ (thinking of $f$ as an element of $A$); then $f^{\alpha} \cdot (1 + f) = f^{\alpha - 1} \cdot (f)$, with the LHS in $M_1$ and the RHS in $M_2$, contradicting that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are direct summands.  Thus we must have $f=0$ and we are back in the situation above.

Comment: why does such an $\alpha$ exist such that $f^{\alpha +1}=0$?

Comment: you can assume $f$ is only in degree $> 0$ so a high power has to have high degree and lands in in the ideal $I$

Comment: Ah I see now. One more question: how do you know that there is an $f\in M_2$ such that $1+f\in M_1$?

Comment: If you have any pure degree 0 element in any subrepresentation then that subrepresentation is the entire representation by the setup of the problem.  I'm being a little sloppy: you want $a + f \in M_1$ and $f \in M_2$ where $a \in k$.

Comment: I understand that if $M_1$ has a constant polynomial then it should be the whole representation, but I  still don't understand why your statement is possible: "you want $a+f\in M_1$ and $f\in M_2$ where $a\in k$".

Comment: Okay, I see.  The argument should probably be like this then: $1 = f+g$ for $f \in M_1$ and $g \in M_2$.  Suppose both have a constant term.  Then there is some large monomial $m$ such that $mf$ and $mg$ have all higher terms killed off in the ideal.  This contradicts that the representations are disjoint.